# get results of two observables from flatmap when finished

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, flatmap

I have two observables, using RxJava and Retrofit, and an observable with a flatmap

1) (tmdbApi.discoverymovies) calls an api and get a list of movies from a certain set of paramenters

2) (addImdbIdToMovieList)takes a list of movies as a parameter and returns that list of movies with imdbIDs added to it.

There's a third function I'd like to run on the movies, but I can't find where to place it.   I can't run it until the movie has an ImdbId associated with it.  If possible I'd like to run it on each movie as it comes in, but without running some list items multiple times, but if necessary I can wait until the list is finished.

Where should I put a call that takes in a movie list and does something to it?

```
    private void getMovies(Params params) {
    listOMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        runTheOtherTwoObservables(params).
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<ArrayList<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList) {
            listOMovies = movieArrayList;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e("zzzzz" , "err", e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d("zzzzz", "running oncomplete");
                for (Movie movie : listOMovies) {
                    Log.d("zzzzz", movie.getTitle() + ": " + movie.getImdbID());
                }

            }
        });
}

private TmdbApi getTmdbApi() {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    return retrofit.create(TmdbApi.class);
}

private Observable<ArrayList<Movie>> addImdbIdToMovieList(ArrayList<Movie> listOfMoviesWithoutIds) {
    TmdbApi tmdbApi = getTmdbApi();

    return Observable.create(emitter -> {

        for (Movie movie : listOfMoviesWithoutIds) {
            tmdbApi.TMDBdetails(String.valueOf(movie.getTmdbID()), getResources().getString(R.string.tmdb_key), "en-us")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Movie>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Movie movie) {
                            String imdbID = movie.getImdbID();
                            movie.setImdbID(imdbID);
                            Log.d("zzzzz", movie.getTitle() + " Set To " + movie.getImdbID());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e("zzzzz", "err", e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.d("zzzzz", "thrrd onComplete");
                        }
                    });
        }
        emitter.onNext(listOfMoviesWithoutIds);
        emitter.onComplete();
    });
}
public Observable<ArrayList<Movie>> runTheOtherTwoObservables(Params params) {
   TmdbApi tmdbApi = getTmdbApi();
    return tmdbApi.discoveryMovies(getResources().getString(R.string.tmdb_key),
            "en-us",
            "popularity.desc",
            params.getInclude_adult(),
            false,
            params.getPrimary_release_date_min(),
            params.getPrimary_release_date_max(),
            params.getWith_genres())
            .flatMap(response -> addImdbIdToMovieList(response.getResults()));
}
```

Comment: why don't you call a flatmap on addImdbIdToMovieList ?

Comment: when I do that it runs before they all have imdbID's and I get an exception in my third function

Comment: that can't happen flatmap is for that purpose only, to handle when the result is ready from a Future.

Comment: doh ok the issue was that one of the movies didn't have an imdbid so it was erroring there.  I set a fallback for null and that solution appears to be working.

Comment: awesome work :)